# Strange behavior in JSON wrapping my objects

Tags: jquery, json

I'm making the following post to my server,

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    data: JSON.stringify({ SecretKey: e.Code, CommentId: e.Id, Direction: direction, VoteType:1}),
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
});
```

When the request posts, it looks like the following:

```
{"Direction":{"Id":1,"Code":"1234-5678-9012","Description":"This is 1 comment."},"VoteType":"1"}
```

Why is `Direction` wrapping elements?  Notice `VoteType` is not affected?  The only difference between `VoteType` and the rest of the variables is that `VoteType` is a literal value -- not referencing an object.

Full model, in case it helps:

```
var model = {
    Id: ko.observable(0),
    Code: ko.observable(""),
    Description: ko.observable(""),
    Comments: ko.observableArray(),
    vote: function (e, direction) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: { SecretKey: e.Code, CommentId: e.Id, Direction: direction, VoteType:1},
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
    });
    },
    secretVote: function (e, direction) {
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            data: { SecretKey: e.Code, Direction: direction, VoteType:0},
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        });
    },
    comment: sendComment
}
```

Comment: I think you don't need to do `JSON.stringify`. jQuery handles that for you.

Comment: @Pythonian That's what I thought too, and how I originally had it, however, without `JSON.stringify`, I receive a null object server-size in Web API method for the object.

Comment: I think `direction` is an object when you pass it in. the keys(Id,Code,Description) do not match the missing ones (SecretKey,CommentId) make sure e.Code and e.Id are defined

Comment: @JuanMendes The JSON I posted is captured is in FireBug -- prior to hitting the server.

Comment: What does `JSON.stringify(direction)` give you? `{"Id":1,"Code":"1234-5678-9012","Description":"This is 1 comment."}`, that's why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `JSON.stringify`, it will attempt to serialize everything. `description` (identified by the key `Description`) points to a complex object that has internal properties and so `JSON.stringify` will serialize that into JSON. `VoteType` is a key and so will be serialized as just `VoteType`.

Also, the reason you're not seeing `SecretKey` and `CommentId` is that they are `undefined` and so will not be serialized by `JSON.stringify`.

To sum up, this has more to do with the *values* of the keys than the keys themselves. In the first case, `Direction` refers to a complex object whereas in the second case `VoteType` refers to an integer.

On another note, there is no need for you to serialize your data using `JSON.stringify`; jQuery will do that for you.

Answer (score 0):

This:

> JSON.stringify({ SecretKey: e.Code, CommentId: e.Id, Direction: direction, VoteType:1})

Can yield:

> {"Direction":{"Id":1,"Code":"1234-5678-9012","Description":"This is 1 comment."},"VoteType":"1"}

If your `e.Code` and `e.Id` are not defined (`SecretKey` and `CommentId` field are then removed) and if `direction` object is:

> {"Id":1,"Code":"1234-5678-9012","Description":"This is 1 comment."}`